# Probability P(Omega or B)

Tags: probability

Let P(A) = 0.2, P(B) = 0.5, and P(C) = 0.3. What is the value of P(Ω υ B)?

So the way I was thinking about this was that since omega is the whole sample place would this just be the sum of all three events? Meaning this will equal one?

Comment: What does $v$ mean? If it means union ("$\cup$", `\cup`), then $P(\Omega \cup B) = P(\Omega) = 1.$ 

detexify.kirelabs.org

Comment: sorry about that. Yes, it means /cup

Comment: Try a slightly different problem with $P(C) = 0.2$. Would you then assert, using your proposed method, that $P(\Omega) = P(A)+P(B)+P(C)=0.9$ instead of $1$ as an axiom of probability theory says?

Answer (score 0):

Right, the probability of the union of two events is never less than the maximum of the probabilities of each of the two events separately and since $P(\Omega)=1$ that's your answer.  Events $A,C$ are irrelevant.